# Can you use the ternary operator with STORE in pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, ternary-operator

In apache pig if I want to conditionally store some data and I try to do it like so:

```
data1 = ....;
data2 = ....;
STORE (condition ? data1 : data2) INTO '$output' USING PigStorage(",");
--assuming pig is smart enough not to run the query for data1 or data2 depending on the condition
```

Then I get a syntax error:

```
SEVERE: exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file test.pig, line 38, column 6>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('
Failed to parse: <file test.pig, line 38, column 6>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('
```

Am I using the ternary operator in pig incorrectly, and if this is not possible is there another way I can achieve conditional storage in pig, preferably without writing a UDF.

Comment: whats the schema of data1 and data2? are they same?

Comment: @GauravPhapale yes in this case they are the same, but I feel like it shouldn't matter

Comment: just added the answer with the assumption of same schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ternary operation in the STORE statement as you are trying to do in the question.
You can add the condition column to both data1 and data2, then take a UNION and then filter the UNION'd data based on condition value.

```
data1 = ....
data1a = CROSS data1, condition;

data2 = ....
data2a = CROSS data2, condition;

data12 = UNION data1a, data2a;
final = FILTER data12 BY condition == true;

STORE final INTO '$output' USING PigStorage(",");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This requires calculating both relations, I was hoping to avoid that, basically I want to be able to configure running it one way or another. I will concede there is a very small chance the optimizer will figure this one out but I doubt it. Also you might want to edit the answer to have `not conditon` in data2a

Comment: no, PIG is not that smart. also, I dont think we can conditionally evaluate a relation in PIG.

Comment: Well my hope in my initial attempt was that it would be easy to see that one of the relations was never outputted in anyway and optimize it out, only issue being that the ternary can't output an alias I guess

Comment: I did not get you. Do you want to avoid 'evaluating' 1 of the relation or 'outputting' 1 of the relation? Evaluating is out the question wrt PIG.